# How to use a numeric id in Google Healthcare api FHIR

Tags: hl7-fhir, google-healthcare-api

I need to change uuid to numeric id, but I can't find how to make this.

Someone can help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create resources with any ID you want (that is allowed by the FHIR spec) if you set [enabledUpdateCreate](https://cloud.google.com/healthcare/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.datasets.fhirStores#FhirStore.FIELDS.enable_update_create) to true in your FHIR store config.

> This determines if the client can use an Update operation to create a new resource with a client-specified ID.

For example

```
curl -X PATCH \
    -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8" \
    --data '{
      "enableUpdateCreate": true
    }' "https://healthcare.googleapis.com/v1/projects/PROJECT_ID/locations/LOCATION/datasets/DATASET_ID/fhirStores/FHIR_STORE_ID?updateMask=enableUpdateCreate"
```

Then you can create a new Patient with ID `1` like this

```
curl -X PUT \
     -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth application-default print-access-token)" \
     -H "Content-Type: application/fhir+json; charset=utf-8" \
     --data '{
         "resourceType": "Patient",
         "id": "1"
     }' \
"https://healthcare.googleapis.com/v1/projects/PROJECT_ID/locations/LOCATION/datasets/DATASET_ID/fhirStores/FHIR_STORE_ID/fhir/Patient/1"
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Problem resolved. :D

Comment: If your question has been resolved it's appreciated if you Accept this answer